# Sort and remove duplicates

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gawk

Please can you help me to solve this problem.

I would like to sort column 1, 2 to be able to delete the duplicates in column 1, keeping always the first 2 records.

The objective in the sort is to keep in the second column diff numbers not the same.

example

I got this

```
3039949085;**19**;1195616938480000;1  ;V2
3039949085;**19**;1195616938480000;2  ;V2
3039949085;**30**;1195616938480000;2  ;V2
```

after the sorting should be

```
3039949085;**19**;1195616938480000;1  ;V2
3039949085;**30**;1195616938480000;2  ;V2
3039949085;**19**;1195616938480000;2  ;V2
```

i use this code

```
sort -t';' -k1,2n -k4 file | gawk -F';' 'a[$1]++<2
```

My input file is:

```
2995347947;6;1195617034732000;1  ;V3
2995347947;9;1195617034732000;1  ;V3
2995347947;6;1195617034732000;2  ;V3
2995347947;9;1195617034732000;2  ;V3
3039948773;14;1195616284532000;1  ;V2
3039948785;14;1195616747632000;1  ;V2
3039948785;25;1195616747632000;1  ;V2
3039948785;14;1195616747632000;2  ;V2
3039948785;25;1195616747632000;2  ;V2
3039949061;19;1195615542032000;1  ;V2
3039949061;19;1195615542032000;2  ;V2
3039949061;30;1195615542032000;2  ;V2
3039949073;19;1195616109632000;1  ;V2
3039949073;19;1195616109632000;2  ;V2
3039949073;30;1195616109632000;2  ;V2
3039949085;19;1195616938480000;1  ;V2
3039949085;19;1195616938480000;2  ;V2
3039949085;30;1195616938480000;2  ;V2
3039949373;10;1195615559208000;1  ;V2
3039949373;11;1195615559208000;1  ;V2
3039949373;10;1195615559208000;2  ;V2
```

output I got

```
2995347947;6;1195617034732000;1  ;V3
2995347947;9;1195617034732000;1  ;V3
3039948773;14;1195616284532000;1  ;V2
3039948785;14;1195616747632000;1  ;V2
3039948785;25;1195616747632000;1  ;V2
3039949061;19;1195615542032000;1  ;V2
3039949061;19;1195615542032000;2  ;V2
3039949073;19;1195616109632000;1  ;V2
3039949073;19;1195616109632000;2  ;V2
3039949085;19;1195616938480000;1  ;V2
3039949085;19;1195616938480000;2  ;V2
3039949373;10;1195615559208000;1  ;V2
3039949373;11;1195615559208000;1  ;V2
```

But i will like to get the following output

```
2995347947;6;1195617034732000;1  ;V3
2995347947;9;1195617034732000;1  ;V3
3039948773;14;1195616284532000;1  ;V2
3039948785;14;1195616747632000;1  ;V2
3039948785;25;1195616747632000;1  ;V2
3039949061;19;1195615542032000;1  ;V2
3039949061;30;1195615542032000;2  ;V2
3039949073;19;1195616109632000;1  ;V2
3039949073;30;1195616109632000;2  ;V2
3039949085;30;1195616938480000;2  ;V2
3039949085;19;1195616938480000;1  ;V2
3039949373;10;1195615559208000;1  ;V2
3039949373;11;1195615559208000;1  ;V2
```

My problem is in the sort step

Appreciate your help.

Comment: You say you want to keep only 2 first records with equal 1st column but in your sample output I see `3039949061` 3 times.

Comment: it is a mistake should be only 2 times

Comment: Edit your question, don't write it in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this awk to print unique sets of `$1,$2`:

```
awk -F';' '!a[$1,$2]++'
```

Full example:

```
sort -t';' -k1,2n -k4 file | awk -F';' '!a[$1,$2]++'

2995347947;6;1195617034732000;1  ;V3
2995347947;9;1195617034732000;1  ;V3
3039948773;14;1195616284532000;1  ;V2
3039948785;14;1195616747632000;1  ;V2
3039948785;25;1195616747632000;1  ;V2
3039949061;19;1195615542032000;1  ;V2
3039949061;30;1195615542032000;2  ;V2
3039949073;19;1195616109632000;1  ;V2
3039949073;30;1195616109632000;2  ;V2
3039949085;19;1195616938480000;1  ;V2
3039949085;30;1195616938480000;2  ;V2
3039949373;10;1195615559208000;1  ;V2
3039949373;11;1195615559208000;1  ;V2
```

Comment: @user2734334 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.